# Python tuple to dictionary with elements in tuples as keys and assigning fixed values to return keys with max and min rolling sum of values

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I am having an issue in converting a dataset in python where I think having them from tuple to keys and assigning some fixed values are going to help me. To give a small example, I have the following input data as arrays of tuples (not necessarily sorted):

```
[(1,3), (2,7), (10, 15)]
```

The output I want is, for first element of each tuple, I want them assigned value 1 while for the 2nd element of each tuple, I want them assigned value of -1, that is the output I want will be a dictionary like the following:

```
{1:1, 3:-1, 2:1, 7:-1, 10:1, 15:-1}
```

Then I want to sort this dictionary with the keys and return keys and values with maximum and minimum of rolling sum. I think I shall be able to figure out this part however, I  am stuck with the needed tuple to dictionary conversion as I stated above.
Does anyone have any suggestion or solution?

Comment: What should the dictionary be for the input `[(1, 2), (2, 3)]`?

Comment: Something like this could do the trick: `dict(zip([x for y in lst for x in y], (1, -1) * len(lst)))`

Comment: Good question. Won't ```[(1, 2), (2, 3)]``` give duplicate keys with 2?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
# initialize variables:
tuple_list = [(1,3), (2,7), (10, 15)]
data = {}

# iterate over each point (tuple) in tuple_list:
for point in tuple_list:

    data[point[0]] = 1
    data[point[1]] = -1

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Itertools will make short work of stuff like this. You can cycle through `(1, -1)` with [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and flatten the original with [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Then zip the together:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

l = [(1,3), (2,7), (10, 15)]

dict(zip(chain(*l), cycle([1, -1])))

# {1: 1, 3: -1, 2: 1, 7: -1, 10: 1, 15: -1}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can work also:

```
d={}
lst = [(1,3), (2,7), (10, 15)]

for x in lst: d={**d,x[0]:1,x[1]:-1}
```